# Laravel Request::input Call to undefined method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm new to Laravel framework and now facing with a problem while trying update logged users info.

Route:

```
Route::post('/user/{id}', function (Request $request, $id) {
    return App\Http\Controllers\UsersController::update($request, $id);
});

public static function update($request, $id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);
    $user->name = $request->input('name');
    ...
    $user->save();
    ...
}
```

Error:

> FatalErrorException in UsersController.php line 24: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::input()

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Add the following import at the top of your file:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

otherwise your controller gets injected instance of **Request** class from global namespace that is an alias of **Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request**./

Comment: excuse me for a noob question, but I thought all public methods can be access using facade?

Comment: That's true, but this only works if you call given method statically, e.g. 'Request::input()`. Only static calls are forwarded to the instance methods of the object behind the facade.